# I need to add a comment on several products in WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce, product

I have used the following code to apply a message to a single product, but I now need to add the same message to several defined products by their ID. Any suggestions?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_quantity', 'mjl_displays65' );
function mjl_displays65(){
global $product;

$product_id = $product->get_id();

    
    If ($product_id == "4174")
    
{echo '</br><div class="body"><STRONG>THIS PRODUCT IS END OF LINE. PLEASE CALL OR EMAIL TO CHECK STOCK BEFORE ORDERING.</STRONG></div>';
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put the defined IDs in an array.

try this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_quantity', 'mjl_displays65' );
function mjl_displays65(){
global $product;
 $number_array = array(4174, 4175 );//add IDs here
  if ( in_array($product->get_id(), $number_array ) ) {     
echo '<br><div class="body"><STRONG>THIS PRODUCT IS END OF LINE. PLEASE CALL OR EMAIL TO CHECK STOCK BEFORE ORDERING.</STRONG></div>';
    }
}
```